# Cell is ViewController or View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I used UITableViewCell like this.

```swift
class WeatherListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var degree: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rainPercent: UILabel!
    var weather: String?
}
```

I thought the cell is kind of `View` so it can't have not UI stuff.
But sometimes I added a value like `weather` for using hidden info and the cell worked like `ViewController`.

Can I use cell like this?

Comment: _"I thought the cell is kind of View so it can't have not UI stuff."_ Why did you think a `UIView` cannot hold any kind of properties? `UITableViewCell` is a `UIView` subclass, not a `UIViewController` subclass (as the documentation clearly state), however, this makes no difference to weather it can hold a `String` property or not.

Comment: I thought, if the cell is view, it can't hold the weather value because it is not presenting the value. Do I have wrong idea?

Comment: Yes, you have the absolutely wrong idea. A `UIView` acts like any other Swift `class`, it can hold any type of variable.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks a lot. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` is a class like any other in iOS. If you derive from it you can extend its capabilities and therefore add properties and functions.

Like you have already done you can add `@IBOutlet`s that represent parts of the cell's UI but you can also add non-visible fields that you just use within the class to hold information that you need.

Think about functions that you add, they are also not part of the UI but they are within the declaration of your `WeatherListTableViewCell` class.

There could be a function which uses the weather string you already added and extracts information from in, populating your UI elements with their corresponding values.